# php split string without losing delimiter

Tags: php

I have a string that i want to split it to array with

delimiter.
But i don't want to lose these delimiters and i want them to be a part of array.

my string is something like below:

```
$str = "<h3>hello</h3>this is my test and <h3><span>bye</span></h3>";
```

and what i want to reach is this:

```
array(
    '<h3>hello</h3>',
    'this is my test and ',
    '<h3><span>bye</span></h3>'
);
enter code here
```

is there any way to do it?

thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `preg_split` with the `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE` option:

```
$arr = preg_split('/(<h3>.*?<\/h3>)/', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
```

You will probably want to also include the `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` option so that you don't get empty values when two `<h3>` blocks are next to each other or at the start or end of the string i.e.

```
$arr = preg_split('/(<h3>.*?<\/h3>)/', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/DVRpr)